# Pass user input to new instance of class

Tags: vb.net, class

Alright, I have looked through 20 pages on here and can't find what I'm looking for... I've seen it in C# and other languages.. but not Visual Basic..

Say I have a class:

```
Public Class Cars
    Private doors as integer
    Private Liters as double
    Private otherStuff as string

 ' more code'
end class
```

Say I also have a Form.. an inputForm we'll call it that has numerous textboxes for users to input these characteristics.  The first textbox is labeled nameTextBox.  Is there any way to assign the string value of that textbox as a new car?

something to the likes of..

```
dim nameTextBox.value as new car
```

??

Comment: You need two things: 1. A constructor that accepts a string. 2. `Dim Car As New Car(nameTextBox.value)`

Comment: okay.. do I need anything within that constructor? or just: Public Sub New(ByVal name as string)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields in your class are private, so they arent of much use - no other code will be able to see those values.

```
Public Class Car
    Public Property Make As String
    Public Property Model As String
    Public Property Year As Integer

    ' something the class may use/need but doesnt expose
    Private DealerCost As Decimal 

    ' the constructor - called when you create a NEW car
    Public Sub New(mk As String, md As String)
        Make = mk
        Model = md
    End Sub
    ...
End Class
```

By specifying only a constructor which takes params, I am saying that you cannot create a new car without specifying those properties.  If the constructor takes no params, then you can create an "empty" car object and set each property individually.  You can do both - called *overloading* - so you can create a car with or without the Make and Model at the outset.

As Public Properties, other code can examine them to see what kind of car this is.

```
Dim myCar = New Car("Toyata", "Corolla")
myCar.Year = 2013
myCar.Color = Color.Blue
```

The text used of course can come from user input:

```
Dim myCar = New Car(tbMake.Text, tbModel.Text)
Dim yr As Int32
If Integer.TryParse(tbYear.Text, yr) Then
    myCar.Year = yr
Else
     ' ToDo: scold user
End If
```